# I was trying vagrant up and I had this error

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

1. When I run vagrant up it gives me this error. I'm trying to create a virtual machine with the command line interface.

   ```
    vagrant up
    Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    ==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/focal64' version '20220804.0.0' is up to date..
    ==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports..
    ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    ==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
    ==> default: Running pre-boot' VM customizations..
    ==> default: Booting VM...
    There was an error while executing 'VBoxManage', CLI used by Vagrant for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

    Command: ['startvm', "fOf87cbc-9f24-409f-b1b7-a105544a838c", "--type", "headless"]

    Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Not in hypervisor partition (HVP=0 (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
    VBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)
    VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
   ```

Comment: I successfully ran 'vagrant init ubuntu/focal64' but when I run the 'vagrant up' on git bash, I keep getting that error code

Comment: You will need to change the setting in your bios to enable the VT-x..